# Does the server Firewall which allows Outgoing traffic on Port 80/TCP also allow on Port 80/UDP?

Tags: security, http, tcp, udp, firewall

Is the Windows Firewall which accept outgoing traffic on port 80/TCP allow outgoing traffic also when we use UDP protocol.

Does a Firewall in most cases control the port number only or controls the used Protocol also ?

Comment: Is this relevant in SO? It should be asked somewhere else in StackExchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP and UDP ports are entirely different from each other. So, TCP/80 has nothing to do with UDP/80, except for the number. From a firewall's perspective, they are entirely separate things with separate rules.