# Which Firewall Rule Allows 1433 TCP Port

Tags: sql-server, tcp, port, plesk, windows-firewall

First of all [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280136/does-the-server-firewall-which-allows-outgoing-traffic-on-port-80-tcp-also-allow) does not contain my answer.

I want to find which firewall rule allows specific port `1433`

In my server, Plesk has been installed and "MS SQL over TCP protocol" firewall rule is **disabled**. Somehow I can connect to the SQL Server from remote connection. There is one firewall rule allows 1433 TCP Connection but which one? Is there any command to find which firewall rule allows 1433.

Comment: This is not a programming question, flagging to move

Comment: Where can I ask the question?

Comment: Probably belongs better on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Yes this is not programming question. I asked command in CMD or Powershell. Do you know the answer?

Comment: I am not sure about anyone else, but this is a rule I have always had to add myself.

Comment: @JMabee I don't understand

Comment: What don't you understand? The firewall rule top open up port 1433 is not created automatically.  You have to create that rule on your own.

Comment: When plesk is installed some firewall rules have been created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110526/why-doesnt-get-netfirewallrule-show-all-information-of-the-firewall-rule)

Run as administrator

```
cls
Get-NetFirewallPortFilter | Where-Object { $_.LocalPort -Eq "1433" } | Get-NetFirewallRule |
Format-Table -Autosize -Property DisplayName,
@{Name='Protocol';Expression={($PSItem | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter).Protocol}},
@{Name='LocalPort';Expression={($PSItem | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter).LocalPort}},
@{Name='RemotePort';Expression={($PSItem | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter).RemotePort}},
@{Name='RemoteAddress';Expression={($PSItem | Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter).RemoteAddress}},
Enabled, Profile, Direction, Action
```

Comment: Result is MS SQL over TCP protocol TCP. However, Enabled property is False. So, This does not give me correct result.

Comment: Port configuration can get pretty complex, multiple rules in a string, like:  "1433, 1434, 1435 - 1440". $_.LocalPort -Eq "1433" assumes a single port configuration. You might want to adjust the where condition $_.LocalPort -Eq "1433" to parse the value of $_.LocalPort, (split it by commas, create ranges if pairs are delimited by - and find if port 1433 is covered by any rule)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to figure this out is through netevents.

1. Start command line as administrator.
2. Run `netsh wfp cap start keywords=19`
3. Let the traffic flow through port 1433
4. Run  `netsh wfp cap stop`
5. Open Wfpdiag.xml in Wfpdaig.cab generated by above step.
6. Search for all **NetEvents** with `<localPort>1433</localPort>` and get filterId from `<classifyAllow>`
7. Search for the filterId and the `<displayData>` should tell you which rule allowed the packet.